# What is the preferred form of Cyrillic to use for handwriting?

Tags: алфавит

When writing Cyrillic by hand is it preferred to write in roman type italic type? For example, should I write г, *г*? д or *д*? и and й or *и* and *й*? т or *т*? Or should one use cursive to write? What type is normally written in handwriting in countries that use Cyrillic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [preferred](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_cursive) form is the standard modern Russian Cyrillic [cursive](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/17/Russian_Cursive_Cyrillic.svg). Russians do not normally write in typed block letters, everybody uses the cursive. If you prefer the block letters, you can choose any letter shape available, all of them will be understood. The only limitation is that mixing italic and block shapes should be avoided (like по *г* ода), or else what you wrote will be looked at as something written by a barely literate person.

Comment: I would say that writing some letters in slanted-roman-slightly-cursive style is quite common. I, for instance, can't stand the shape of cursive "Т", and have always written it in the slanted roman form.

Answer (score 1):

Preffered form is the cursive, as said Yellow Sky. But also one more thing is not use two or more forms of one letter in the same text. For example, if you started to use "д" as "*д*", do not use it as "*g*" or "д" in the same text.