# Is it becoming the norm for Russians to handwrite in block letters in informal situations?

Tags: узус, typography, культура

Is it more common to see block letters nowadays, especially on the internet? For example, I've linked to a Twitter artist who (among many others) seems to handwrite in block letters in their comics. I was wondering whether this is the norm and, if so, whether this is a trend set by younger generations or only applicable in specific circles (eg. in comics and the like).

https://twitter.com/KaySD999/status/849705771596120064?s=20&t=J9CLx2qeCBZqtgku_T0wHg

Comment: I have never seen a comic with non-block letters.

Answer (score 1):

You basically gave a single example, built some conclusions based on that example and then asked a question based on those conclusions. There's indeed a [trend for lesser use](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/19764/do-adult-russians-normally-hand-write-cyrillic-as-cursive-or-as-block-letters) of cursive - or rather, for less strict rules for cursive, I'd say.

However in this particular case I believe there's no direct connection with this trend. While the history of comic culture in Russia is shorter than that of, say, the US or France, there's still such a thing as Russian comic culture. And, just like in English or French comic strips, cursive was not a thing in Russian comics either.

Here's an example of a Soviet comic:

[image]

Here's an example of an early nineties Russian comic (one that I was a huge fan of as a child):
[image]

Here's an example of a modern Russian comic (a shitty one, according to my taste)
[image]

That said, we can talk about at least 30 years of lettering traditions in Russian comics.